# Wolfram alpha error in global minimization?

Tags: optimization, wolfram-alpha

Let us consider the function

$$f(x,y)= x + y^2 - \ln(x+y)$$

If you try to minimize it using Wolfram Alpha (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+x%2By%5E2-ln%28x%2By%29), it founds a local minimum at $(x,y)=(1/2,1/2)$, but it can't find a global minimum. 
But that local minimum should also be the global one, since the function is a convex one and the domain is convex.

Am I wrong or is Wolfram Alpha wrong?

---

Ok, thanks to everybody who answered or commented, but perhaps I was not clear when writing my question: I knew that $(1/2,1/2)$ is a local minimum, and, since the $f(x,y)=x+y^2-ln(x+y)$ is a convex function and the domain is $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x+y >0\}$, which is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then a well kwown result in convex optimization ensures that $(1/2,1/2)$ is also a global minimum.
Then perhaps I should have written: "why does Wolfram Alpha says 'no global minima found' when I ask to minimize $f(x,y)$?"

As far as I can understand from your answers, that sentence from Wolfram Alpha means only that it is not able to find a global minimum, not that the global minimum does not exist, is this correct?

Comment: Wolfram never claimed it *wasn't* a global minimum. Detecting local minima is generally much simpler than analyzing their global character, so Wolfram simply never bothered with the latter.

Comment: It could be thinking, "Uh-oh, if $x+y$ is negative, then the function takes complex values, and there's no order on the complex numbers... better not say anything". Computer algebra systems are kind of stupid sometimes.

Comment: I ran into this today, where wolfram alpha could tell me the range of my function was f(x, y) >= 2, and it could identify a local minimum whose value was f(0, 1) = 2, but it still claimed "no global minimum found".

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, if I add " for x + y > 0.0" to the OP's wolfram alpha input, it reports a global minimum at (0.500002, 0.499999). I guess the explicit constraint makes it solve the problem numerically in some way that lets it identify the global minimum, but at the cost of some rounding error. Weirdest of all, saying "x + y > 0" rather than 0.0 gives you the same rounding error, but with it only identifying the point as a local minimum.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of $f$ is the set of pairs $(x,y)$ for which $r=x+y>0.$ Using $x=r-y$ our function can be expressed nicely in terms of separate functions of $r,y$ as 
$$(r-\ln r)+(y^2-y).$$
Using one variable calc, the min of the first bracketed term is $1$ (at $r=1$), while the min of the second is $-1/4$ (at $y=1/2$).

This shows your function satisfies $f \ge 1 -1/4=3/4.$ That this is actually the global minimum then follows since $f(1/2,1/2)=3/4.$

If Wolfram explicitly says no global minimum exists, that is incorrect. However in some cases a computer algebra system may not deal with implied domains well... [I just looked at Wolfram output you link to, and it only says there *is* a local min, not that there is not a global one.]

Answer (score 1):

Find the partial derivatives:

$$\frac{∂}{∂x}(f(x,y))=1-\frac{1}{x+y}\:\:\:\:(1)$$
and
$$\frac{∂}{∂y}(f(x,y))=2y-\frac{1}{x+y}\:\:\:\:(2)$$

Set $(1)$ equal to $0$:
$$0=1-\frac{1}{x+y}$$
$$\frac{1}{x+y}=1$$
$$x+y=1\:\:\:\:(3)$$

Set $(2)$ equal to $0$:

$$0=2y-\frac{1}{x+y}\:\:\:\:(4)$$

Put $(3)$ into $(4)$:

$$0=2y-\frac{1}{1}$$
$$y=\frac{1}{2}\:\:\:\:(5)$$

Put $(5)$ back into $(3)$:

$$x+\frac{1}{2}=1$$
$$x=\frac{1}{2}$$

So $(x,y) = (\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ is our potential extremum. Now find our second partial derivatives, and perform the second derivative test for a function of two variables:

$$f_{xx} = \frac{1}{(x+y)^2}$$
$$f_{xy} = f_{yx}=\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}$$
$$f_{yy}= \frac{1}{(x+y)^2} + 2$$

And now the test:

$$D(x,y)=f_{xx}(x,y)f_{yy}(x,y)-(f_{xy}(x,y))^2$$

$$D(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})=(\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2})^2})(\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2})^2} + 2)+(\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2})^2})^2$$

$$D(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})=4$$

Also note that:

$$f_{xx}(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2})^2}=1$$

And so, we have $D(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})>0$ and $f_{xx}(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})>0$, so by the second derivative test for a function of two variables, we conclude that $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ is a local minimum, and the only extremum. As you stated in your question, this point must be a global minimum. WolframAlpha simply said it was a local minimum, and didn't say that it wasn't a global one:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the first order conditions: 
$f_{x} = 1 - \frac{1}{x + y} = 0$ 
$f_{y} = 2y - \frac{1}{x + y} = 0$

So $\frac{1}{x + y} = 1$, which gives us $y = \frac{1}{2}$. It follows that $x = \frac{1}{2}$.

So Wolfram Alpha seems to be correct here. Note you should also verify that $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ is a minimum, but this is straight-forward to do.